# substring based on symbols and letters

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to substring for some values in postgres starting with some letters and ending with a symbol. Please see example below,

Some row for a column

'value: 12423, store: target, date: 2010-08-22'

How do I substring for target in the column?

The new column becomes 'target'

Answer (score 0):

```
substring('value: 12423, store: target, date: 2010-08-22' from 'store: ([^,]*),')
```

More information [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-matching.html).

Answer (score 0):

First split the string on the comma ',' producing a vector/array of 3 items.
Then split the second item in the vector on the colon ':' and read off the second part of that split. Consider the functions `string_to_array()` and `split_part()`.